# Use restful api to invoke nightmare scraping multi site with promise wrapper

Tags: node.js, api, web-scraping, promise, nightmare

I would like to scrap multi-site with one restful api, I use express to implement it.
But I only triggered nightmare successfully in first time with my api,
when I call again my api I can't trigger nightmare any more :(

Have any idea?

another question, in below case, I need to instantiate new Nightmare object individually , so that I can scrap three different site, have any smarter way to achieve that?

bellow `getScrap` is my apiControler function with express `Router` GET callback,
you also could check in gist: 
https://gist.github.com/sevenLee/7091f8c56ccad3c0551b512f725af7da

```
import Nightmare from 'nightmare';
import cheerio from 'cheerio';

let nightmare = Nightmare({show: false});
let nightmare2 = Nightmare({show: false});
let nightmare3 = Nightmare({show: false});

const urlObject = {
  site1: 'http://www.site1.com',
  site2: 'http://www.site2.com',
  site3: 'http://www.site3.com'
};

export function getScrap(req, res){
  let result = {};

  result.site1 = {
    topList: []
  };
  result.site2 = {
    topList: []
  };
  result.site3 = {
    topList: []
  };

  const pro1 = Promise.resolve(
    nightmare
      .goto(urlObject.site1)
      .wait(200)
      .evaluate(() => {
        console.log('site1 into evaluate');
        return document.querySelector('.ninenine').innerHTML;
      })
      .end()
  )
  .then((html) => {
    let $ = cheerio.load(html);
    let tt = $('.horizontal-li');
    let sections = $(".section-board-title");

    sections.each((index, elm) => {
      if($(elm).text() === 'TopList'){
        $(elm).next('ul').find('li').each((index, elm_li) => {
          let title =$(elm_li).find('.cabinet-instruction').text();
          let price =$(elm_li).find('.cabinet-middle .price').text();
          let imgSrc = $(elm_li).find('.cabinet-img').attr('data-temp-src');
          if(title !== '' && price !==''){
            result.site1.topList.push({
              title,
              price,
              imgSrc
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('site1 scrap err:', err);
    return res.status(400).send({reason:'site1 scrap err'});
  });

  const pro2 = Promise.resolve(
    nightmare2
      .goto(urlObject.site2)
      .wait(200)
      .evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('.ninenine').innerHTML;
      })
      .end()
  )
  .then((html) => {
    let $ = cheerio.load(html);
    let tt = $('.horizontal-li');
    let sections = $(".section-board-title");

    sections.each((index, elm) => {
      if($(elm).text() === 'TopList'){
        $(elm).next('ul').find('li').each((index, elm_li) => {
          let title =$(elm_li).find('.cabinet-instruction').text();
          let price =$(elm_li).find('.cabinet-middle .price').text();
          let imgSrc = $(elm_li).find('.cabinet-img').attr('data-temp-src');
          if(title !== '' && price !==''){
            result.site2.topList.push({
              title,
              price,
              imgSrc
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('site2 scrap err:', err);
    return res.status(400).send({reason:'site2 scrap err'});
  });

  const pro3 = Promise.resolve(
    nightmare3
      .goto(urlObject.site3)
      .wait(200)
      .evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector('#layout').innerHTML;
      })
      .end()
  )
  .then((html) => {
    let $ = cheerio.load(html);
    let sections = $(".pditem");

    sections.each((index, elm) => {

      let title = $(elm).find('.name').text();
      let price = $(elm).find('.price').find('span').eq(1).text();
      let imgSrc = ['www.site3.com',$(elm).find('li').eq(1).find('img').attr('src')].join('');

      result.site3.topList.push({
        title,
        price,
        imgSrc
      });
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('site3 scrap err:', err);
    return res.status(400).send({reason:'site3 scrap err'});
  });


  Promise.all([pro1, pro2, pro3])
  .then(values => {
    res.json(result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    return res.status(500).send({reason:err.toString()});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(From my original answer at [segmentio/nightmare#715](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/715).)

> But I only triggered nightmare successfully in first time with my api,
>   when I call again my api I can't trigger nightmare any more

It looks like you're defining your instances outside of `getScrap()`, then calling `.end()` inside of `getScrap()`, which will end and destroy the Nightmare/Electron instances.  Once they are ended, they can no longer be used.  Try moving the creation of your Nightmare instances inside of the `getScrap()` method.

> another question, in below case, I need to instantiate new Nightmare object individually , so that I can scrap three different site, have any smarter way to achieve that?

Depends on what your use case is.  You could use a single Nightmare instance and iterate over the URLs, but that will take more time as Nightmare execution *must* be sequential.  If you're curious on how to do such a thing, [this article from `nightmare-examples`](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/async-operations-loops.md) might be worth reading.

Finally, it's probably worth pointing out that based on your above code, you don't have to use `cheerio`.  You could use `.evaluate()` and CSS queries to accomplish what you want, I think.

Comment: I will check nightmare-example article, too. nice tutorial!